# How does the creation of an AMI on AWS work and why is the creation time unpredictable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Creation date: `September 23, 2019 at 9:22:06 PM UTC+2`

`21:48`: still waiting for completion

`21:53`: completed

Sometimes it takes 15 minutes and sometimes longer. How does a creation of an AMI work and why is the creation time unpredictable?

Comment: Are you creating the AMI from the same type of EC2 instance?  If so what type of instance is it (e.g. t2, m4 large, etc)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating an AMI, you are making a copy of your EBS volumes. This utilizes block storage and will only need to process the diffs of your EBS snapshots. If you changed a lot of data in your EBS or don't have a previous snapshot, it will take longer to create your AMI.

Here is a quote from the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html

> Depending on the size of the volumes, it can take several minutes for
>   the AMI-creation process to complete (sometimes up to 24 hours). You
>   may find it more efficient to create snapshots of your volumes prior
>   to creating your AMI. This way, only small, incremental snapshots need
>   to be created when the AMI is created, and the process completes more
>   quickly (the total time for snapshot creation remains the same).